# Android-Graphics : BitmapFactory() returns only immutable object for src images

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing a problem while decoding an image:

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.smile);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(bMap);
```

as `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` returns an immutable object, which we cannot pass to the constructor of `Canvas` class.

Can I use the function

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),Resource, option opt)
```

as `BitmapFactory.options()` is used for making the bitmap factory to return only mutable objects, no matter if the image is from "src" or dynamic.

Please help me out to create an image into canvas.